# Swift: type does not conform to protocol

Tags: swift, swift2, protocols

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {
    var a: A { get }
}

struct StructA: A {}
struct StructB {
    var a: StructA
}
extension StructB: B {}
```

This produces the error :

> Type 'StructB' does not conform to protocol 'B'

The `StructA` already conform to protocol `A`, and `StructB`'s property `a` return `StructA` type. That seems pretty a protocol B conformed type.

But why?

---

Xcode version 7.3 which Swift version is 2.2

Comment: Could you try `a = StructA()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To better illustrate the problem with your current code, let's say you have a `StructC : A`.

Your protocol `B` says that you can assign `StructC` to `a` (as it conforms to `A`) – but `StructB` says you cannot assign `StructC` to a `StructA` type. Therefore `StructB` doesn't conform to `B`.

The solution is either to change the type of `a` from `StructA` to `A` [as Rahul says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36812441/2976878), or better yet, you could use generics.

The advantage of using generics is once you create your `StructB` with a given `a` – that property's type will be inferred by Swift, giving you better type safety. For example, once you assign a `StructA` to it, its type will then be `StructA`. If you assign a `StructC` to it, its type will be `StructC`.

To do this, we just have to add an `associatedtype` to protocol `B`. This will define a 'placeholder' type that we can then implement in a type that conforms to `B`. We can then define the generic type `T` in `StructB` that will provide the 'implementation' of `AType` – making sure it conforms to `A`. Therefore, we are now free to assign either `StructA` or `StructC` to `a`, without losing type safety.

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {

    // new associated type to hold the type of "a" which conforms to A
    associatedtype AType:A
    var a: AType { get }
}

struct StructA: A {}
struct StructC:A {}

// define the new generic T which conforms to A
struct StructB<T:A> {

    // define the type of a as the generic T, which conforms to A (and thus conforms with the protocol)
    var a : T
}

extension StructB: B {}

let s = StructB(a: StructA())
s.a // "a" is now of type StructA

let s1 = StructB(a: StructC())
s1.a // "a" is now of type StructC
```

Answer (score 2):

Because Swift is statically typed and does not depend on dynamic dispatch. You could do something like below.

```
import UIKit

protocol A {}
protocol B {
    var a: A { get }
}

struct StructA: A {}
struct StructB {
    var a: A = StructA()
}
extension StructB: B {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am reworking this code from swift 3.0.

extension WallPost: PFSubclassing {

static func parseClassName() -> String {
return "WallPost"
}
}

This generates the error:
Type 'WallPost' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing'

Unavailable class method 'object()' was used to satisfy a requirement of protocol 'PFSubclassing'

Any idea of why this is happening and how I can resolve it?  I wanted to fix this before updating to swift 4.0 / 5.0

Thanks so much for the help!